# NextJS ISR revalidate doesn't work for static pages when i18n is active

Tags: next.js, internationalization, interrupt

I have faced this problem in my real world project. I will use the blog-starter demo from NextJS documentation for simplicity.

Nextjs version **13.0.3**.

I have a main page. I use `getStaticProps()` with `revalidate` key for it, this way I enable ISR. When I build the project, the logs explicitly indicate that ISR for the main page is enabled. And content actually changes when i change one in CMS.

```
// pages/index.tsx

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const allPosts = getAllPosts()

  return {
    props: { allPosts },
    revalidate: 60,
  }
}
```

[image]

But. As soon as I enable the internationalization feature in `next.config.js`, the ISR for the main page stops working, which can be seen both in the logs and in fact: changing content in CMS does not result in rebuilding of the main page and content on the main page does not change by the change in CMS. Only a full rebuilding of the application helps.

```
// next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['uk', 'en'],
    defaultLocale: 'uk',
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

The expected behavior is that the ISR keep working for main page. Researches on Google, in the Nextjs repository and issues led to nothing. I would be grateful for help and advice.

[image]